# Dynamic change a lot of textures is very low performance

Tags: three.js, textures

I am a newbie in Three js. In my project, I need draw a ground with a lot of texture. The ground has many layers, every layer has 4 textures and textures in different layers are different size. Below picture describe the ground:
[image: Ground]
  Ground is one mesh has multiple material:

```
this.mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MultiMaterial(materials));
```

Suppose I have a car it always at center of ground, in other word, center of all layers. When it move, the ground will translate to make sure the car always at center. So everytime ground translate, I need to update texture in new position.
  The picture draw 3 layers for illustration, but in my project is 6 layers. So everytime all texture change, that means need to change 6 * 4 = 24 textures, and that cause low fps in my program.
   This is my function to load texture from indexed DB every time a texture change:

```
Ground.prototype.loadTextureFromIndexedDB = function (url, materialIndex) {
var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
loader.crossOrigin = '';
loader.load(url,
    function (texture) {
        var groundMaterial = ground.mesh.material.materials[materialIndex];        

        groundMaterial.map.dispose();
        groundMaterial.map = texture;
        groundMaterial.map.anisotropy = ground.maxAnisotropy;
        groundMaterial.map.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
        groundMaterial.map.needsUpdate = true;
        img = null;
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);           
    });
}
```

I have tried many solutions. One of them is make a mesh with a BufferGeometry and MultiMaterial with array of ShaderMaterial. As what I known, it is the best for performance in THREE JS, isn't it? If it is then maybe THREE JS is not powerful as I thinked. Should I change to another API for my project?
Anyone suggest me any solution to make higher performance in my program? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You dont give any information on why you need all these textures, You also don't give any information on how you are implementing it now. Without this information, it's hard to help you.

Comment: Thanks @2pha for your comment. I was edited my question, so I hope you can find what I am wrong in my code.

Comment: So you have 1 ground plane with a multimaterial material on it? What sort of materials are you using in this multimaterial? Have you considered writing your own ShaderMaterial?

Comment: The order of materials is from the smallest size layer to the largest size layer. I also search some topics say about ShaderMaterial but have not yet implemented. Could you write a example use ShaderMaterial with changing multiple textures? Thanks!

Comment: You still have not said what type of materials you are using. So it's hard to know exactly how you are implementing it. Your use of the word "layers" is also confusing. There are many examples of simple shaders [here](http://blog.2pha.com/experimenting-threejs-shaders-and-shadermaterial).

Comment: Materials is array of MeshPhongMaterial. Layers are squares with different size and one contains 4 textures. You can see the above picture, that has 3 layer with 3 different colors. And in my project, the color would be replaced by textures. Thanks.

Comment: When I mentioned a ShaderMaterial, I meant a single ShaderMaterial instead of the MultiMaterial. I was thinking along the lines of having a ShaderMaterial that accepts all 6 textures and doing all the translation and layering inside this shader